# Max height transition is not working when the max-height property change dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.sidebarCategory').forEach(el =>{
      el.addEventListener('click', e =>{
          let sub = el.nextElementSibling
          if(sub.style.maxHeight){
              el.classList.remove('opened')
              sub.style.maxHeight=null
          }
          else{
              document.querySelectorAll('.sidebarSubcategories').forEach(element => {
                  element.style.maxHeight=null
                  element.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('opened')
              })
              el.classList.add('opened')
              sub.style.maxHeight = sub.scrollHeight + "px";
          }
      })
  })
  document.querySelectorAll('.sidebarSubcategories > div:not(.sidebarSubSubcategories)').forEach(el =>{
      el.addEventListener('click', e =>{
          let sub = el.nextElementSibling
          if(sub!=null && sub.classList.contains('sidebarSubSubcategories'))
          {
              if(sub.style.maxHeight){
                  sub.style.maxHeight=null
                  sub.style.marginBottom=0
                  sub.style.padding='0 30px'
              }
              else{
                  sub.style.marginBottom='15px'
                  sub.style.padding='15px 30px'
                  sub.style.maxHeight = sub.scrollHeight + 30 + "px"
                  el.parentNode.style.maxHeight=el.parentNode.style.maxHeight.slice(0,el.parentNode.style.maxHeight.length-2) + sub.scrollHeight + 30 + "px"
              }
          }
      })
  })
```

```css
.main{
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      width: 400px;
      height: 300px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background-color: aquamarine;
  }
  .sidebarCategory{
      color: white;
      position: relative;
      height: 60px;
      min-height: 60px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      font-size: 20px;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      font-weight: 600;
      fill: white!important;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding-left: 15px;
      transition: 0.4s;
  }
  .sidebarCategory.opened{
      background-color: rgba(3, 63, 109, 0.588);
  }
  .sidebarSubcategories{
      max-width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      background-color: rgba(3, 63, 109, 0.588);
      max-height: 0;
      transition: 0.4s;
      overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  .sidebarSubcategories > div:not(.sidebarSubSubcategories){
      max-height: 45px;
      /* height: 45px; */
      position: relative;
      min-height: 45px;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      padding: 0 30px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--blue);
  }
  .sidebarSubSubcategories{
      max-height: 0;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      transition: 0.4s;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 5px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin: 0 15px;
  }
  .sidebarSubSubcategories > div{
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.2s;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      border-radius: 5px;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 49%;
  }
  .sidebarSubSubcategories > div:hover{
      background-color: #f3f3f3;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="sidebarCategory">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </div>
        <div class="sidebarSubcategories">
            <div>
                Subcategory
            </div>
            <div class="sidebarSubSubcategories">
                <div>Sub Subcategory</div>
                <div>Sub Subcategory</div>
                <div>Sub Subcategory</div>
                <div>Sub Subcategory</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                Subcategory
            </div>
            <div>
                Subcategory
            </div>
            <div>
                Subcategory
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

See the code, the first drop-down is not closing smoothly if I interact with the second drop-down menu.
I am changing the max-height property to create an accordion. I have placed another accordion inside the accordion. But when I interact with the inside accordion, the out-side accordion's transition does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is this line
`el.parentNode.style.maxHeight.slice(0,el.parentNode.style.maxHeight.length-2) + sub.scrollHeight...."`

Your adding a string and number which will always concatinate so '123' + 4 = the string '1234'. You need to parse to an int (you also won't need to slice off the px)

```
//Instead of 
el.parentNode.style.maxHeight.slice(0,el.parentNode.style.maxHeight.length-2)
//Do this            
parseInt(el.parentNode.style.maxHeight)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `sidebarSubcategories` element has no defined height. It has a `max-heigth` of `0` and then it is set to `null` via JavaScript.

The default value of `height` is `auto`, so, when you set `maxHeight` to null, you are setting `max-height` to `auto`, and transitions don't work on `auto` values.
That's because the browser doesn't know which value to transition to.
If you really need this and you can't a priori set each `sidebarSubcategories`' `height`, you'll need to store the `innerHeight` of each `sidebarSubcategories` (when it's expanded) and applying it back when expanded again.

Comment: If you were right the other transitions wouldn't either work. Only after interacting with the inner submenu does the outer transition stop working.

Comment: Actually the problem was I wrote hilarious JavaScript, adding height would add another problem that's why I didn't add it intentionally